# Where is the bing maps 6.2 documentation?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am trying to upgrade a piece of code from version 6.2 of Bing maps to version 7.0. I am having trouble because certain methods don't seem to match up between the VEMap class and the Microsoft.Maps.Map class.

I have found the documentation for version 7.0 at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx. This is great, and has been a big help. The problem is, I can't seem to find any documentation for version 6.2. I found this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429637.aspx which seems to be documentation for 6.3, but it isn't as detailed, and doesn't give a full list of methods for the VEMap class.

One of my main problems is that in the 6.2 version, this code was called:

map.Clear();

map.Find();

I didn't write the code, so I'm not sure what these functions were being used for, but I don't see any similarities in the 7.0 version.

I also had a problem with the 7.0 version. After creating the map, I tried calling this function: map.getVersion();

But, it doesn't seem to work, even though it's in the documentation as a method for the map class.

Any help on these issues would be helpful,

Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42730/Microsoft-VEMap-Using-Pure-Javascript

Also, here is the VEMap class definition. Partially in Korean, as I can't find the english version with the menu at the side.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/bb429572.aspx